# How to remove black border around hyperlinked image?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When I turn an image (`<img>`) into a hyperlink (by wrapping it in `<a>`), Firefox adds a black border around the image.  Safari does not display the same border.

What CSS declaration would be best to eliminate the border?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
img {
    border: 0
}
```

Or old-fashioned:

```
<img border="0" src="..." />
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This solution helped me out a lot, wish I'd found it before the 2 hours of frustration!  But I think using "a img{border: 0;}" is a better fitted solution to the original problem - the emphasis on the initial "a" because the problem only occurs when an image is wrapped in a hyperlink

Answer (score 9):

Just add:

```
border: 0;
```

or:

```
a img {
  border: 0;
}
```

to remove border from all image links.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

in the code use border=0.  so for example:

```
<img href="mypic.gif" border="0" />
```

within css

```
border : 0;
```

under whatever class your image is.

Comment: attention: Your <img> tag is not correct. Either you have to use " to quote the border attribute value (because XML requires that), or you have to remove the / before the ending > (because SGML/HTML doesn't allow that)

Answer (score 3):

```
a img {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's invalid CSS: '0' does not have a unit. Should just be "border-width: 0;".

Comment: @BobbyJack Of course 0 needs a unit. Even if it can be derived from the context, all numbers (and 0 is a number) need a unit to be meaningful. The browser automatically adds the 'px' if you leave it off, cleaning up for your laziness - but it still needs to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img {
  border-style: none;
}
```