# Why does my image have a black square around it but just with IE :-(

Tags: css

I have the following code block:

```
<li><a ><img class='ico' src='../../Content/Icons/home.png' />Home</a><img class='sep' src='../../Content/Images/sep1.png' /></li>
```

It works as expected BUT around the 16x16 ico image there is a black border. I already have the CSS as follows:

```
li a {padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 18px; 
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none; position: relative;bottom: 7px;
}
```

I have no problem with Firefox and Chrome but just with IE.

Does anyone know how I can fix this. I would have thought it would have obeyed the text-decoration: none for the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How switch off image border in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958688/how-switch-off-image-border-in-ie) Also, http://stackoverflow.com/q/49966/331508 .

Answer (score 4):

You just need to remove the default `img` border:

```
img {
    border: 0
}
```

That should preferably go near the top of your CSS.