# Drupal 7: Omega -> IE7 Border issues

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

how to remove border of link in IE7 ?

Env is Drupal 7 with Omega theme

i have tried the solutiion of following links as well.

1.[How to remove borders around links in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910209/how-to-remove-borders-around-links-in-ie)

2.[How can I remove the outline around hyperlinks images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images)

3.[how to remove black border around hyperlinked image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966/how-to-remove-black-border-around-hyperlinked-image)

4.[how to remove blue border around links in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284954/how-to-remove-blue-border-around-links-in-ie9)

Could you please some one put light on this.

Thanks in advance,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Does your css show up when you inspect the source? 
If not you might need to specify an IE specific css in your theme .info file.

Answer (score 0):

use the !important key word and may be you should clear the cash in your website administrator